# How to run the code depending on the value of a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently created a code that is based on a for loop. It reads the value of each row in the first column and completes the rest of the line for each row.

However, I want to complete the rest of the line based on the value of the 2nd column of each line.

Indeed, the second column now has either the value "OPEN" or "CLOSED". I want the program to run if the cell is "open" and I want to move on to the next row if the cell is "closed".

Any idea how I can do so?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub StressTest()

    Dim index As Integer
    Dim dateColumn As Integer
    Dim portfolioDate As String
    Dim portfolioName As Variant
    Dim ParametricVar As Double
    Dim AuM As Double
    Dim PreviousVar As Double
    Dim PreviousAuM As Double
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim workB As Workbook
    Dim min As Double
    Dim max As Double


    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set sheet = ActiveSheet


    portfolioDate = InputBox("Please enter date under the following form : YYYY-MM", "Date at the time of Stress Test", "Type Here")
    Debug.Print "Current portfolio date is: " & portfolioDate




      For index = 3 To 37
    If sheet.Cells(index, 3) = "OPEN" Then
                dateColumn = MatchHeader(portfolioDate)
                portfolioName = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & index & "").Value


                strPath = "G:\Risk\Risk Reports\VaR-Stress test\" & portfolioDate & "\" & portfolioName & ""

                Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath)

                ParametricVar = Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("VaR Comparison").Range("B19")
                PreviousVar = sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 7).Value
                AuM = Workbooks(portfolioName).Worksheets("Holdings - Main View").Range("E11")
                PreviousAuM = sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 9).Value


                Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Scenarios - Main View")
                Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("VaR - Main View")
                Set rng2 = ws2.Range("J16:J1000")
                Set rng1 = ws1.Range("11:11")

                max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(rng2)

                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn).Value = ParametricVar / AuM
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 2).Value = AuM
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 4).Value = ws1.Cells(10, Worst(rng1))
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 5).Value = Loss(rng1)
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 6).Value = max
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 1).Value = (ParametricVar - PreviousVar) / PreviousVar
                sheet.Cells(index, dateColumn + 3).Value = (AuM - PreviousAuM) / PreviousAuM





                wb.Close Savechanges:=False

        Next index

        Else: If sheet.Cells(index, 3) = "CLOSED" Then Next index

End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the code you have this far.

Comment: If you show us your code, we should be able to help. It might be worth reading: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What hinders you to use a simple `If`-statement?

Comment: I know how to start by an if statement however, I'm not sure how to move on to the next index if the cell value is "closed"

Comment: A simple line like `If Cells(index, 2) <> "Closed" Then` to check a value, if different to `Closed` it will continue the code, if equal to `Closed` it will skip the rest of the code and go to next iteration.

Comment: just use an `If` statement that contains the code inside the loop

Comment: Can you check my modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of the iteration should look like:

```
'First bit of code
For index = 3 To 37
    If Sheet.Cells(index, 3) = "OPEN" then
        'Code
    End if
Next index
'Continue your code
```